# Xcode confused with IQAir Api Parsing

Tags: json, swift, xcode, api

so I use I am trying to parse through this data:

```
{"status":"success","data":{"city":"Sunnyvale","state":"California","country":"USA","location":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-122.03635,37.36883]},"current":{"weather":{"ts":"2020-07-23T00:00:00.000Z","tp":25,"pr":1009,"hu":44,"ws":6.2,"wd":330,"ic":"02d"},"pollution":{"ts":"2020-07-23T00:00:00.000Z","aqius":7,"mainus":"p2","aqicn":2,"maincn":"p2"}}}}
```

I am trying to get a hold of the `aqius` result, as well as the `tp`...
Here is my code right now, I have created these structs:

```
struct Response: Codable{
    let data: MyResult
    let status: String
}

struct MyResult: Codable {
    let city: String
}
```

As you can see, I have gotten city, and I can confirm it works because when I get the request and `print(json.data.city)` it prints "Sunnyvale".
But how would I get the other values? I have been stuck on how to obtain values within the `location` , `current` and `pollution` data structures, how would I do this?
Thanks

Comment: You can use "https://app.quicktype.io/" to auto generate Swift Model from Json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are tools that automatically generate `Codable` models from json string like: https://app.quicktype.io)

So your base struct models looks like below;

```
// MARK: - Response
struct Response: Codable {
    let status: String
    let data: DataClass
}

// MARK: - DataClass
struct DataClass: Codable {
    let city, state, country: String
    let location: Location
    let current: Current
}

// MARK: - Current
struct Current: Codable {
    let weather: Weather
    let pollution: Pollution
}

// MARK: - Pollution
struct Pollution: Codable {
    let ts: String
    let aqius: Int
    let mainus: String
    let aqicn: Int
    let maincn: String
}

// MARK: - Weather
struct Weather: Codable {
    let ts: String
    let tp, pr, hu: Int
    let ws: Double
    let wd: Int
    let ic: String
}

// MARK: - Location
struct Location: Codable {
    let type: String
    let coordinates: [Double]
}
```

Decode;

```
let jsonData = jsonString.data(using: .utf8)!
let model = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: jsonData)
```

Comment: Bro thank you so much! That  is an amazing tool will use it